# Is it possible to use the verb particle 过 for future events?

Tags: grammar

I know it's possible to the use perfective aspect particle 了 for future events, eg:

> 你家少爷长大了准能当个二流子。

I have yet to find example of similar occurrences with 过. Is it even possible to use it in other situations than past events?

Comment: Deserves upvotes, not downvotes! The distinction between aspect and tense is a major reason that Chinese particles can be difficult to learn (coming from an English-speaking background), so showing examples where particles that could be misunderstood as "past tense" are used in the future is useful in explaining the distinction!

Comment: Chinese language doesn't have a strong sense of Tense as in English. Tense in Chinese is something conveyed by the whole sentence, not by individual (or group of) character/particle/phrase in the sentence. More often than not the tense of a sentence depends on the context. Example A: "你长大了" by itself is almost same as present perfect tense in English, but "你长大了就明白了" talks about the future. Example B: "我去邮局取包裹" by itself is almost same as simple present in English, but in "我昨天收到邮局发的领取包裹通知单. 我去邮局取包裹. 在回家的路上碰到了他." it talks about the past.

Comment: @孤影萍踪 I agree, and that's why I commented. Chinese doesn't have grammatical tense, it has grammatical **aspect**. That's why it's important to show that `了` and `过` are **not** about tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, only for events in the near future.

> 等我喫過(了)，咱們再走。 (= 喫了再走)
>   等我玩過(了)，咱們再走。 (= 玩了再走) It's better to use "玩夠了" in this case.
>   等我弄過(了)，咱們再走。 (= 弄了再走)

You must say "等 sb" to make it natural.

Note: this is less used than only a "了".

Comment: I think 够, as in 玩够了 would be more appropriate for the cases you mentioned.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Yes you are right. I've changed it =)

Answer (score 2):

Some times you don't have to say 等。

我们吃 **过（了）** 饭后就去看电影。

明天，我们的行程是：上午去看画展，看 **过（了）** 画展后去海边游泳。中午……下午……

看 **过（了）** 这封信，你就知道他为什么离开这个城市了。

Answer (score 0):

These sentences mentioned above are misleading, as 过 is not the experience aspect marker in them. It is an RVC, so the usage is different. The aspect suffix can not be followed by 了.

Comment: I think other answers are trying to highlight the use of the particle in future perfect.

Answer (score 0):

过 used in sentences above is not a particle, it is a resultative compound. Particle 过 can not be followed by 了, so the sentences are correct, but the usage of 过 is different.